# In Armadillo is it possible to set the memory after the variable has been declared?

Tags: memory, armadillo

I have a class with an Armadillo vector as an instance variable.  I know that I can create an Armadillo vector using a memory location as a constructor argument.  However, I don't see a way to set the vector memory after the vector has been created.

I need to do this because the memory address for the vector is passed as constructor to the class. It would be nice to be able to do something like:

```
Class foo {
  arma::Row<float> myVec;

  foo(float *memptr, int size)
  {
    myVec.set_mem(memptr, size);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach may work. First construct a temporary vector from the provided `memptr`. Then move the temporary vector to `myVec` using [std::move()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move). This will also cause the temporary vector to become invalid.

```
Class foo {
  arma::Row<float> myVec;
  
  foo(float *memptr, int size)
  {
    arma::Row<float> temp(memptr, size, false, false);
    myVec = std::move(temp);
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that `memptr` has to point to valid memory for the lifetime of the `foo` object. If that cannot be guaranteed, change the constructor of `temp` so it copies the memory.

```
    arma::Row<float> temp(memptr, size, true, false);
```